# ¿Como puedo enviar datos de un excel a BD en java, me lee pero el error esta al parecer en la consulta ? Gracias

Tags: java, apache-poi

[[image]

En la imagen se puede observar el error que al parecer se encuentra en la linea donde se ejecuta el SQL

```
public static void cargar() throws IOException, SQLException {
        Conectar cn = new Conectar();
        PreparedStatement ps;

    try {
        Connection com = cn.getConnection();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Archivo.xlsx"));

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int numFilas = sheet.getLastRowNum();

           for (int i = 1; i <= numFilas; i++) {
               Row fila = sheet.getRow(i);
            ps = com.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO productos (Codigo,Nombre,Cantidad,Valor) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
            //ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into productos (Codigo, Nombre, Cantidad, Valor) values (?,?,?,?)");
             ps.setString(1, fila.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
             ps.setString(2, fila.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
             ps.setDouble(3, fila.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue());
             ps.setDouble(4, fila.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue());
            ps.execute();
           }
        com.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Excel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Añade tambien el codigo donde haces la llamada a la funcion, por favor

Comment: Cual es la linea 119?? ese archivo existe???

Comment: es la linea del PrepareStatemen y la consulta sql

Comment: no, ya lo intente asi

Comment: cn.getconnection no esta devolviendo nada.. verificalo... cierro la pregunta por duplicado de nullpointerexception.. si no es asi, por favor pone tu error como texto, y verifica que realmente getconnection devuelve algo que no sea null (por ejemplo con un if)

Comment: y avisame si no es asi... usa mi nombre @gbianchi en un comentario

Comment: @gbianchi trate con "IF" pero me sigue marcando el error en ps = com.PrepareStatement("insert into productos (Codigo,Nombre,Cantidad,Valor) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

Comment: com no es null?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/263750/como-puedo-enviar-datos-de-un-excel-a-una-bd-en-java

Comment: no es null, es igual a la conexion.getConnection();

Answer (score -1):

Debes establecer el driver JDBC con el método `setConnectionFactoryClassName`